# sddm-greeter cpu usage, lxqt

Tags: cpu-load, lxqt, sddm

I've got an annoying issue that I am trying to troubleshoot and could use some help!

I have 10 lxqt VM's managed via proxmox on a rather old machine. The OS needs to be very light and low on resource usage. Right now, each VM idles at 15% cpu, which seems rather high. Multiply by 10VMs and well, the idle resource usage is a bit problematic.

I've been able to track it to a process that constantly uses about 7% cpu. sddm-greeter.

-Quick disclaimer, I am a total noob with linux, trying to learn but not easy. I am the user of those VMs and my sysadmin is on the busy side and can't help. Still, I like to find solutions and fix stuff myself. This is a bit out of my league at the moment tho, which is why I come here for help!

Whenever the sysadmin logs on via console (and then logs out), the sddm-greeter service stops and is no longer seen until next reboot of the VM. The VM then idles at 7% cpu, which feels much more acceptable.

I have to use the VMs via RDP, but that doesn't kill the sddm-greeter process. Only whenever they log via console/terminal (without doing anything else than just logging in and out).

Any ideas as to what is happening? Normal? Anything that could fix this?
Its running on dual intel e5430, 24gb ram (yeah its old, but that's what I have to work with and I don't mind the challenge of being as efficient as possible with my tasks).

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details

Comment: sorry, thats Debian 4.19.194-2. lxqt 0.14.1

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *The package you gave is old & doesn't match with any supported release of Ubuntu/Lubuntu that is on-topic on this site*

Answer (score 0):

sddm-greeter uses this much CPU for cursor blinking in the password field. Use [Tab] button on keyboard to move away from the password field. Cursor will disappear from the password field and CPU load become less then 1% of 1 CPU thread.